# React vite serve application runing with TestCafe directly goes to about:error, gives proxy error

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, vite

I am transitioning our frontend from `create-react-app` to `vite` and I suddenly noticed that the `development`  and `preview` builds of vite do not work together with Testcafe for some bizarre reason.

The exact error I get is:

```js
 yarn testcafe .\src\tests\main\desktop\helppagina.test.ts
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 104.0.5112.102 / Windows 10

 My Fixture
 × My Test

   1) undefinedFailed to load the page at "http://localhost:3000/gms/app/help".
      Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the "retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.
      You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".

      Error details:
      Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "http://localhost:3000/gms/app/help".

      Browser: Chrome 104.0.5112.102 / Windows 10

  // 4 more snipped for length

 5/5 failed (50s)

 Warnings (1):
 --
  Was unable to take a screenshot due to an error.

  Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 3 (CLOSED)
      at sendAfterClose (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:979:17)
      at WebSocket.send (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:405:7)
      at Chrome._enqueueCommand (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\chrome-remote-interface\lib\chrome.js:286:18)
      at C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\chrome-remote-interface\lib\chrome.js:88:22
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Chrome.send (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\chrome-remote-interface\lib\chrome.js:87:20)
      at Object.handler [as captureScreenshot] (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\chrome-remote-interface\lib\api.js:32:23)
      at BrowserClient.getScreenshotData (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\testcafe\src\browser\provider\built-in\dedicated\chrome\cdp-client\index.ts:312:50)
      at BrowserProviderPluginHost.takeScreenshot (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\testcafe\src\browser\provider\built-in\dedicated\base.js:87:32)
      at BrowserProvider.takeScreenshot (C:\Users\j.claassens\Documents\workspace\wlis\gms\mmi-end-to-end-test\node_modules\testcafe\src\browser\provider\index.ts:409:13)
```

- My Vite dev server is running as `http://localhost:3000/gms`
- My Testcafe server starts on `http://localhost:<port_from_testcafe>/<some_random_id_from_testcafe>/`
- Google Chrome version launched by testcafe: `104.0.5112.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)`
- This problem also happens with `firefox` and `edge` configured for TestCafe, and it did NOT happen with create-react-app.

I have more info (the package.json's for both projects, file/folder screenshots and the testcaferc and vite config files) on this gist: https://gist.github.com/favna/38c0358a9827da176d4ccf02cfffe502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to set `server.host` to `true` in the `vite.config.ts` instead of the previous value of `'localhost'`.

I have no idea why this is the solution considering TestCafe goes to `'localhost'` as well, but whatever the reason, the goal of fixing the issue has been achieved.